# Dealing with trees of different node types

Tags: c++, tree

I am having a tree data structure that can have different types of nodes deriving from one `TreeBaseNode` class. I have made the tree nodes of type `TreeBaseNode *` which gets assigned to objects of different Special nodes at run time. 
How can I access `aNodeAttribute` from the `TreeBaseNode*` pointer while traversing the tree on the tree is generated (if the node is of type `SpecialNodeA` which I can identify from `NodeType`)

```
class TreeBaseNode
{
public:
    int NodeType;   
    TypeA commonNodeAttributeA,
    TypeB commonNodeAttributeB; 
};

class SpecialNodeA : public TreeBaseNode
{
private:

    TypeD aNodeAttribute

public:
    SpecialNodeA(int type)
    {
        NodeType = type;
    }
    //Methods   
};

class SpecialNodeB : public TreeBaseNode
{

private:

    TypeE bNodeAttribute;

public:
    //Methods


};
```

EDIT: changed the types

Comment: If you're accessing everything through pointers-to-base-class, it implies that you *don't* care what type a particular object is.  But from your question, it sounds like you *do* care.  This sounds like you need to re-think your design...

Comment: I understand that the design is bad. How could I modify it. I could have just one node type with all the attributes, but some of it would not be used (depending on the NodeType). That again would be bad design, right?

Comment: @iNoam: Without some idea of how you intend to *use* your data structure, it's hard to say...

Comment: @Oli Depending on the `NodeType` I want to use the attributes to estimate something. It is done outside the class while traversing through the nodes. For instance if it is a `SpecialNodeA`, I would call a function with `commonNodeAttributeA`, `commonNodeAttributeB` and `aNodeAttribute` as parameters.

Comment: @iNoam: Ok.  But if `aNodeAttribute` and `bNodeAttribute` are interchangeable (i.e. if @Mihran's answer will solve your problem), then you may as well replace them with a single attribute in the base class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no polymorphism of data-members of clases in c++, but you can use polymorphism of function-members. So you should declare `virtual int getNodeAttribute(){}` in your base class. And reimplement it in two Derived classes to return attribute what you want.

Comment: Ok, I get it. But would that be a flawed design if I do it that way. Or would you rather have just one node class (with some of the attributes active at a time depending on the NodeType)?

Comment: This is correct, assuming that the OP doesn't care whether he gets `aNodeAttribute` or `bNodeAttribute`.

Comment: No, this is not bad design. But I have a question to you @iNoam. If in both derived classes your attribute is Integer, why not make it part of base class? And if there is possible other types of attributes, then why not use boost::any or boost::variant?

Comment: Actually it is an over-simplified representation of my problem. In the actual scenario they are all of different types.

Comment: Then your question is not clear. Because this case virtual function wouldn't help you. And also you can't declare template of virtual functions. So think boost::variant and boost::any are better way to put in base class as possible attribute and don't worry at all.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Mihran's suggestion would be to use `dynamic_cast<>` to cast those nodes that you know are of type `SpecialNodeA` from `TreeBaseNode` down into a `SpecialNodeA` and then just call an appropriate member function to retrieve the attribute you're after.

In this particular scenario you can even do away with the `NodeType` member in the base class as a `dynamic_cast<SpecialNodeA>` on a node that isn't of this type will simply return a null pointer. I'm not too fond of hierarchies where the base class has to have knowledge of its derived types as that does away with some of the benefits of a class hierarchy and tends to suggest the design isn't as clean as it should be.

Comment: Great answer! I've completely forgotten about casting.

Comment: This answer is correct.  But a design that relies on `dynamic_cast` is just as un-clean!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the extra information in the comments, why not add a public `virtual int estimate() = 0;` to the base class (assuming that the result of the estimation is an `int`), and override it in the derived classes?  i.e. tie the estimation specialisations to the specialised classes.  That way, you don't have to deal with polymorphic code to extract the type-specific fields.